# Subsequent REST call is blocked until previous one is finished

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, rest, resteasy

I Have REST service

```
@Path("/rest")
@Component
public class MyRestService
{
    @Inject
    private MyBean bean;

    @GET
    @Path("/do")
    public String start()
    {
        this.logger.info("Before do " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        String result = this.bean.do();
        this.logger.info("After do " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

        return result;
    }
}
```

which calls method of injected Spring singleton bean (with some state inside)

```
@Service
public class MyBean
{
    public String do()
    {
        // do something big...
    }
}
```

When I call ".../rest/do" in browser the first call goes as expected, but if I make same call in another tab this call waits until first is finished to process second call in same thread.

If I do second call as ".../rest/do?async=true" it does not wait and processes second request in new thread, but if I do both requests as ".../rest/do?async=true" - second one again waits for the first one to finish.

What could be the reason for such behavior? Is it actually expected?

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <display-name>My REst</display-name>

    <!-- spring configuration by annotations -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- spring configuration class -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>app.Config</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- to return data according to extension -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.media.type.mappings</param-name>
        <param-value>json : application/json, xml : application/xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- this has to match with resteasy-servlet url-pattern -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- resteasy spring connector (to use DI in rest-resources) -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <!-- this has to match with resteasy-servlet url-pattern -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Bind Jboss's TransactionManager (EntityManagerFactory) to JNDI -->
    <persistence-unit-ref>
        <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/ReferenceDataDS</persistence-unit-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>ReferenceDataDS</persistence-unit-name>
    </persistence-unit-ref>
</web-app>
```

Comment: your servlet container could be configured with a single thread.

Comment: There is nothing in what you've shown us that would indicate why this behavior happens.

Comment: This code is perfectly fine; but the code here does not describe that behavior in any way. You're using an Spring which describes the behavior somewhere, and it is merely using this code for the request definitions. Somewhere in either your container or in Spring is a definition which tells it whether to be single threaded or accept multiple requests or something. Read the configuration notes on your servlet container and try modifying those text files.

Comment: Any ideas what to look for? :) I don't see anything special regarding "thread" neither in web.xml nor in @Configuration annotated class.

Comment: @Taylor please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774193/subsequent-rest-call-is-blocked-until-previous-one-is-finished#comment29412570_19774193

Comment: @Zaphod42 please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774193/subsequent-rest-call-is-blocked-until-previous-one-is-finished#comment29412570_19774193

Comment: you can share your web.xml and spring config files..

Comment: @coder I updated the post with content of my web.xml

Comment: What container are you using?  Tomcat, Jetty, Jboss, etc...  It would be configured in the container's config, not in web.xml.

Comment: @Taylor I use JBoss, could you please tell me where and what to look for?

Comment: No I'm not that familiar with jboss but I'm pretty sure thread pool configs would be discussed in their docs.

Comment: @Taylor It does not actually look like general thread pool problem, as threads are created without problems if I call not the same, but different methods of MyRestService.

Comment: Q1 - Have you tried doing this from a different client? i.e. Another browser, or using curl? It may not be the server that's doing this. Q2 - Do you have any methods which are "synchronized"?

Comment: @Steve

A1 - Yes and client does not matter (Firefox, Opera). What turns out to matter is browser instance - subsequent call is not blocked if one makes it in different browser (tab and window don't help).

A2 - yes, but not in my MyRestService and no synchronized method of MyBean is called. I also checked it with MyRestService method which does not do any calls to MyBean.

Comment: Going by your answer to Q1, any problem is on the client side. If the server can handle simultaneous requests from different clients, then there's nothing for you to do in the Spring controller. I suspect that you need to look into expected behaviour of whatever client library you're using.

Comment: It's look like your servlet container has only 1 thread in pool

Comment: @user2870704 how to check&fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this issue running your application server in debug mode. Do the test with two different clients e.g. Firefox, Chrome, IE, Opera, ... While waiting for the answer pause all the threads.

- If you see only one workerthread active, then the settings of the application server are the problem.
- If you see multiple workerthreads active but one of them is waiting for a semaphore, you have a problem with multiple threads accessing the same resource
- If you have multiple workerthreads active but one of them is waiting for a connection to the persistence store, then you're datasource doesn't have a connection pool.

Answer (score 0):

Since i just spent a whole day to fight this exact problem (without realizing that a changed parameter would have lead to parallel execution):

The culprit is the browser.

- In Chrome, the calls get queued when you call the same resource from two tabs, but executed in parallel when you make the calls from different windows.
- In IE11, they always get executed in parallel
- In Firefox, it doesn't matter whether the calls are from different tabs or windows, they always get queued.

All of them execute them in parallel when the URLs are slightly different, by adding a different fragment or parameter.